# Infinite number of points with modulus 1

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

**Let  $f:D(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic such that $f(0)=1$.
Prove that there are an infinite number of distinct points $z_{n}$ in $D(0,1)$ such that $|f(z_{n})|=1$**

Remark: $D(0,1)$ is the open unit circle

My thought on this matter is to try and prove by contradiction (with the maximum modulus principle).

Assume that there are a finite number of points $z_{n}$ in  such that $|f(z_{n})|=1$

Obviously $z=0$ is one of them, we assume WLOG that $z_{1}=0$

Define $R=min\left \{ |z_{2}|,...,|z_{n}| \right \}$

Let us pick $0<r<R$

By the assumption, $\left |f(z)  \right |<1$ or $\left |f(z)  \right |>1$ for $0<|z|<r$.

If $\left |f(z)  \right |<1$ for $0<|z|<r$ then we get a contradiction to the maximum modulus principle since $f(0)=1$.

If $\left |f(z)  \right |>1$ for $0<|z|<r$   then by the minimum principle we again get a contradiction

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah you are right about the terminology, thx for the correction.

Comment: Your proof is missing one small ingredient. You assume that if if $|f(z)| \ne 1$ for $0 < |z| < r$, then either $|f(z)| < 1$ for $0 < |z| < r$, or $|f(z)| > 1$ for $0 < |z| < r$. While true, this is not something that you can just assume; you have to rule out (by continuity) the possibility that $|f(z_0)| < 1$ and $|f(z_1)| > 1$ for some $z_0, z_1$.